# Stochastic calculus in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Does there exist a more general (than Malliavin or Itô) "Stochastic calculus" defined on $L^1$ space, or some Orlicz space between $L^2$ and $L^1$?

For examples: are there:

- Ito Isometry(-types) of results for L1 processes

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of results you are looking for?  It isn't really clear to me what you mean by the calculus being "defined on" an $L^1$ space.  Certainly there are plenty of results in either area where $L^1$ spaces arise.

Comment: Localization is a standard practice written down in nearly every stochastic analysis textbook. As limits in the definition of stochastic integrals are taken in probability, the generic setting for Ito's formula is neither $L^2$ nor $L^1$ but $L^0$.

Comment: Good point, but does it's isometry types of results exists for L1 processes?

Comment: If you do not require that the expectations are finite but allow an equality infinities, this follows also directly from localization.

Comment: I just wonder what you intend to achieve with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that even for usual Ito calculus wrt to Brownian motion, there is a variation of Ito isometry for processes with infinite variance see. https://nualart.ku.edu/StochasticCalculus.pdf
[image]

Now in terms of a calculus in terms of general processes that are not in $L^{2}$, it gets hard because we lose the Hilbert-space structure and thus nice things such as orthonormality/projections (eg. ["Stochastic Calculus with Respect to Gaussian Processes"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-29/issue-2/Stochastic-Calculus-with-Respect-to-Gaussian-Processes/10.1214/aop/1008956692.full)). Even in Rough-paths, one needs some regularity to do calculus.

One reference I found online for processes with infinite variance is ["On generalized Malliavin calculus"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030441491100278X).

Comment: I like this, your answering all my old open questions:))))